# Error Installing Subclipse in SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: installation, subclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to install [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) in SpringSource Tool Suite (version 2.8.1.RELEASE). Following the instructions at http://www.dariopardo.com/dev-env/how-to-integrate-sts-or-eclipse-with-subversion-svn/, I go to *Help->Install New Software*. I enter the site http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x in the *Work with* text field. Then I get to choose from "Core SVNKit Library", "Optional JNA Library", and "Subclipse".

No matter what components I select, I get the error message "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found." after clicking *Next*. I have no problem with my internet connection.

I got the same error message when trying to install Subclipse from a locally stored `site-1.0.6.zip` file (downloaded from http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240) instead of the above URL.

There seems to be no STS documentation on this. Help, please!

Comment: What is the entire error message that you have?  Which required item cannot be found?

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg: "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found." That's it. No more information, no matter if I tried installing from file or URL. Problem solved by reinstalling STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing STS and reinstalling it. Apparently STS is not the world's most stable software product.

Comment: Perhaps related, I now find myself unable to upgrade STS by using the inbuilt upgrade function: Many  incomprehensible error messages are shown. Another clean install was required, which leads to abandoning your personal settings and customizations. I hope VMware will focus more on stability in future versions of STS.

Comment: worked for me too, market place was not working. Reinstalling, restarting twice made it magically work.

Comment: @jorrebor Glad you solved your problem. Again, I hope stability will be the focus of VMware in their future STS development efforts. Repeated reinstalls and "magical behaviour" is not good enough.